# Swift Protocol Getter and Setter

Tags: ios, swift

Why does Swift automatically allows developers to set the value of the property even though protocol has only declared a getter and not setter. Check out the following code:

```
import Foundation

protocol Pedometer {
    var pedometerAvailable: Bool { get } 
}

class MockPedometer: Pedometer {
    var pedometerAvailable: Bool = true // even though the Pedometer protocol is only getter I can still set ??
}

let mockPedometer = MockPedometer() 
mockPedometer.pedometerAvailable = false // why I can set the value here
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why

Because that's how the language works. The protocol states what the adopter *must* do, not what the adopter *can't* do. A `get` property must have a getter, but nothing says it cannot also have a setter.

(Looking at it from the other direction, a `get set` property must have both a getter and a setter; it *cannot* be read-only, whereas a `get` property *can* be.)

Think about it this way: the adopter must have the properties and functions specified by the protocol, but no law says that it can't have any *other* properties and functions; that would be ridiculous. Well, the setter is effectively another function.

Comment: Thanks Matt! Excellent example and explanation.

Comment: Thanks but then why we need to compulsory define get or set anyway it would get property?

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya That’s just notation. It’s silly but so is a lot of Swift notation. Irrelevant to the question.